# Wordpress won't run a python script but will execute shell commands

Tags: python, php, wordpress

Tried to keep it as simple as possible to understand what the problem is

Test.py

```
print('It works')
```

TestPage.php

```
 /*
 * Template Name: My Template
 * Does stuff
 * @package   PackageName
 * @author    Author
 * @copyright Copyright 
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

        $RESULT=shell_exec('python3 ./Test.py');
        echo 'Result:'.$RESULT;
  ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**What have I tried**

- To remove permissions as the issue I set both files to `777` and made their owner and group the www-data user
- When I run `php Testpage.php` I get the output `Result:It works`
  However, when I load the template in wordpress all I get is `Result:` as the output
- I also tried putting in the fully qualified directory path to both python3 and the python file
- Where it gets really interesting is if I instead do this in the php `echo shell_exec('python3 -c "print(\'It works\')"')` or any other shell command, it will execute as expected. So it's as if there's a block on running actual files

**Is there a specific wordpress setting or apache setting that is required to allow it to run python files?** All of the examples I see online are just as simple as mine.

Comment: Maybe the `shell_exec`'s working directory is not where `Test.py` is located?  Try `$RESULT=shell_exec('python3 ./Test.py 2>&1; echo $?');`, you should get the output error or not and the exit code

Comment: Oh interesting. This is the output from that `Result:python3: can't open file './test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory 2`

Comment: What I said, you're using a relative path `./`, copy and paste the full path to 'test.py'

Comment: @Daviid it did end up being a working directory issue. I must have had some other error before that prevented that test from working for me. I got it to work by putting the full path in for the file. If you make that the answer I'll check it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```php
$RESULT=shell_exec('python3 ./Test.py');
```

You're using a relative path `./`, maybe `shell_exec` is not executing in the same path that `test.py` is in.

Use the full path:

```php
$RESULT=shell_exec('python3 /full/path/to/Test.py');
```

You could also try:
`$RESULT=shell_exec('pwd');`
or
`$RESULT=shell_exec('ls');`

just to verify shell_exec's working directory.